# Generalization of a projective plane?

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, finite-geometry

In the area of finite geometry, a *[projective plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Definition)* is an incidence structure of points and lines with the following properties:

1. Every two points are incident with a unique line
2. Every two lines are incident with a unique point
3. There are four points, no three colinear

I am trying to figure out a generalization of this concept. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Projective_planes_in_higher_dimensional_projective_spaces) one finds the following:

> Projective planes may be thought of as projective geometries of "geometric" dimension two. Higher dimensional projective geometries can be defined in terms of incidence relations in a manner analogous to the definition of a projective plane

However I cannot find a similar definition. What would be a natural generalization of the above three points to the general dimension $d\geq2$?

Comment: I can't create a tag, but I was wondering if it would make sense to have a "finite-geometry" tag.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Axioms_for_projective_space

Comment: Thanks, Quiaochu! I'll try to understand now how this generalizes the definition of a projective plane.